# How to fix "Cannot read property 'first' of null" in javascript, discord bot making

Tags: javascript

So I was developing Discord Bot for my customer and he wanted from me to make a bot that could send an events in his members DMs. I've made the code. Bot executes the function and does send DM to all the members. However, bot stops due an error "Cannot read property 'first' of null".

I tried a lot of things, such as catching console errors etc. But I still do not understand why does my bot stops and writes that console error after me adding that DM code. Console recognize some kind of problem at a line of code that has no actual connections with the Private Message command. It is not even under the same 'bot.on' ... Here is the problem:

```
    if (msg.guild && msg.content.startsWith('!private')) {
      let text = msg.content.slice('!private'.length);
      msg.guild.members.forEach(member => {
        if (member.id != bot.user.id && !member.user.bot) member.send(text).catch(err => {   
            message.reply('I was unable to kick the member');
            console.log(err);
      });
    })
  }
});


**//This right here is a code that can execute the function i wanted to make.^**




bot.on('message', message=> {
    const member = message.mentions.members.first(); // <-- **Console says this property'first' cannot be read (Cannot read property 'first' of null)**


    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    switch(args[0]) {
        case 'ping':
            message.channel.sendMessage('pong!');
            break;
//**Above is a part of the code that has a console error after I added the first code above. Before I added first code there was no such errors and everything worked perfectly.**
```

I expected Bot to execute function and send everyone in the server private message (Event) and continue working.

But instead it executes the function sending everyone desired message but the bot stops as it has an console error.

Comment: Just means `message.mentions.members` is null, so check that and see if it is what you are expecting it to be

Comment: I am not sure what should i do any other suggestions? @Huangism

Comment: When the code gets to the error line, `message.mentions.members` is null, is it supposed to be null sometimes or is it supposed to be something at all times?

Comment: @Huangism Hello, I have managed to fix the problem. I deleted `const user = message.mentions.users.first();` and "const member = message.mentions.members.first();" lines and added them to every case in `switch(args[0])` and it worked perfectly. Thanks for all the help I do appreciate it really much. Cheers.